# setInterval() - no actualiza respuesta de la función

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, setinterval

**Buenas a todos!**

Estoy empezando con JS y en un ejercicio de comparación de los horarios (que funciona bien, quiero establecer *setInterval()* en 1 segundo para que renueva el resultado:

```
let dayOfTheWeek = [
    'Domingo',
    'Lunes',
    'Martes',
    'Miercoles',
    'Jueves',
    'Viernes',
    'Sabado',
];
// indicamos horario para cada dia donde 0 es domingo, 1 es lunes etc...
let schedule = [
    { start: 09 * 60, end: 15 * 60 }, // dimingo 09:00 - 15:00
    { start: 09 * 60, end: 16 * 60 }, // lunes 09:00 - 16:00
    { start: 0, end: 0 }, // martes, cerrado
    { start: 09 * 60, end: 16 * 60 }, // miércoles 09:00 - 16:00 
    { start: 09 * 60, end: 16 * 60 }, // jueves 09:00 - 16:00 
    { start: 09 * 60, end: 16 * 60 }, // viernes 09:00 - 16:00 
    { start: 09 * 60, end: 16 * 60 }, // sábado 09:00 - 16:00 
];
    
    function comprobarHora(today) {
        // separamos dia de la fecha
        let day = today.getDay();
        // selecionamos el dia del objeto "dayOfTheWeek"
        let dayName = dayOfTheWeek[day];
        // adaptamos hora actual con minutos a nuestro formato "time"
        let time = today.getHours() * 60 + today.getMinutes();
        // comparamos resultado "time"  con el horario del dia schedule[day].start y schedule[day].end
        let isOpen = (time >= schedule[day].start && time < schedule[day].end) ? true : false;
        // creamos sugerencias sobre proxima apertura o cierre 
        let sug1 = ((minLeft = (schedule[day].end - time)) <= 60) ? `Cerramos en ${minLeft} minutos` : "Esta cerrado";
        // guardamos resultado en una variable
        let result = `Hoy es ${dayName} y son las ` + today.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }) + (isOpen ? `estamos abiertos <br> ${sug1}` : ' estamos cerrados');
        // si mañana es dia libre, no abrimos 
        let freeDay = ((day + 1 === 2) ? `mañana, ${dayOfTheWeek[2]} estamos cerrados` : `abrimos mañana`);
        // si ya esta cerrado ( hora actual > de la hora de cierre) ? `abrimos mañana ${dayOfTheWeek[day+1]}` : `abrimos a las 9h` : 
        let sug2 = (whenOpen = (time > schedule[day].end)) ? `${freeDay}` : `Abrimos a las 9 `;
        // imprimimos resultado
        document.getElementById("schedule").innerHTML = result;
        // imprimimos sugerencias
        document.getElementById("sugestions2").innerHTML = sug2;
    }
    let today = new Date(); // Día y hora actual
    comprobarHora(today);
```

Así todo va bien, pero cuando intento ejecutar la funcion con

```
setInterval('comprobarHora(today)', 1000);
```

solo la ejecuta, pero no la actualiza con intervalo de tiempo. Alguna sugerencia?

**pd:** Estoy con *operador condicional "ternario"* por esto no uso *"if else"* pero si hay sugerencias sobre la función para lo que sea, se agradece!

Comment: Si mi respuesta solucionó tu inquietud, te agradezco que la aceptes con el check que aparece debajo de la puntuación, así ambos ganamos reputación y será más fácil de identificar si un futuro visitante tiene una duda similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Creo que debes ejecutar una función previa cada segundo en la que capturas la hora actual y la pasas como parámetro a tu función principal.
2. Creo que debes quitar las comillas simples y los paréntesis de la función en `setInterval`

```js
setInterval(ejecutarCadaSegundo, 1000);

function ejecutarCadaSegundo(){
  let today = new Date(); // Día y hora actual
  comprobarHora(today);
};

function comprobarHora(today){
  console.log(today);
};
```

En el ejemplo hago que se muestre por consola la hora actual, pero si el resto de tu código está bien, se ejecutaría sin problema.

Comment: Genial! Metiendo *today* en la función de intervalo es la solución. Gracias!!!